# Java multithreading, capture updated boolean variables

Tags: java

I want to do something like this

```
while (true) {
    if (my_boolean) {  //my_boolean is being updated by other threads
        do something;
        break;
    }
    do something else;
}
```

my problem is, my_boolean is being updated by another method in another thread. Sometimes such updates can be captured, sometimes not. Is there any consistent way to work around this?

Comment: Use `AtomicBoolean`

Comment: Or make the boolean volatile.

Comment: Downvoted. Check any java multithreading tutorial. Or search in StackOverflow before posting a question. This has been asked many times.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare that boolean as `volatile`.

Comment: You don't have to. There are other ways to achieve the same effect.

Comment: This might also lead to a race condition if there are multiple threads that write that variable.

Comment: @Andy Turner: I don't see your point. I didn't say that my solution is the only possible one. Okay, the word "must" might get misunderstood.